# javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#getText', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script

Tags: java, javafx

Beginner with JavaFX, please help me, my code keeps throwing this error. Also, my buttonClick method throws a warning "The type ActionEvent from module javafx.base may not be accessible to clients due to missing 'requires transitive'".

I've tried importing different ActionEvent and EventHandler

My FXML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.SampleController">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="360.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="301.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="345.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="299.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Text fx:id="celsius" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Celsius:" textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="300.611328125">
         <font>
            <Font name="Britannic Bold" size="36.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Text fx:id="fahrenheit" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Fahrenheit:" textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="302.3359375" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <font>
            <Font name="Britannic Bold" size="36.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Text fx:id="kelvin" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Kelvin:" textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="302.490234375" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
         <font>
            <Font name="Britannic Bold" size="36.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <TextField fx:id="textBox" alignment="CENTER" onAction="#getText" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
         <font>
            <Font name="Britannic Bold" size="36.0" />
         </font>
      </TextField>
      <Text fx:id="fahrenheitNumber" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="0" textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="300.97265625" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <font>
            <Font name="Britannic Bold" size="36.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Text fx:id="kelvinNumber" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="0" textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="299.97265625" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
         <font>
            <Font name="Britannic Bold" size="36.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Button fx:id="button" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonClick" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="576.0" text="Convert Now!" translateX="10.0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
         <font>
            <Font name="Britannic Bold" size="39.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

My controller class

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class SampleController {
    @FXML
    private Button button;
    @FXML
    private Text celsius;
    @FXML
    private Text fahrenheit;
    @FXML
    private Text kelvin;
    @FXML
    private Text fahrenheitNumber;
    @FXML
    private Text kelvinNumber;
    @FXML
    private TextField textBox;

    public void buttonClick(ActionEvent event) {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(textBox.getText());
        fahrenheitNumber.setText(Integer.toString(x * (9 / 5) + 32));
        kelvinNumber.setText(Double.toString(x + 273.15));
    }
}
```

A window should be shown but instead, this is thrown.

javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#getText', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
/C:/Users/user/eclipse-workspace/JavaFXSceneBuilder/bin/application/Sample.fxml:42

```
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2621)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:105)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:618)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:778)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2838)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2557)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
at hellofxmlcode/application.Main.start(Main.java:14)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: one problem per question please - that said: a) the stacktrace is telling you exactly what's wrong (there simply is no method getText in your controller, at least not in what you are showing here, add the method in code or remove the handler attribute in the fxml ), b) the warning alerts you to a potential problem in your module-info, fix what it complains about

Answer (score 0):

There's an "on action" event called "getText" associated with your TextField. When you remove it, your program should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late to the party, but had the same issue and got it fixed. The problem is that in your FXML-file, you have declared #buttonclick as a function, however in your code, the function is not marked with the nesseccary @FXML annotation like you have on your attibutes. This breaks the FXML-loader on start since it cannot find the function without the @FXML annotation.

Comment: buttonClick is public .. annotation not necessary - and is not the error, anyway

Comment: ... in other words: this answer is unrelated to the problem in the question and even if it were related it's plain wrong ..